# Calculating homology groups of projective space minus a subspace

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $\mathbb{R}P^{n}$ be the $n$-dimensional real projective space. Assuming that $\mathbb{R}P^{2018}$ is embedded in a canonical way in $\mathbb{R}P^{2019}$, how can I calculate the following homology group:

$H_{1201}(\mathbb{R}P^{2019} \setminus \mathbb{R}P^{2018})$?

In the case of quotients of CW-complexes, a subcomplex $A$ of a CW-complex $X$ has the property that $(X,A)$ is a "good pair" according to Hatcher so we have a long exact sequence that makes computations easier, however here I have one space minus a subspace. Perhaps some slick application of the excision theorem might help? Thanks!

Comment: Isn’t $\mathbb RP^{n+1}\setminus \mathbb RP^n\cong \mathbb R^{n+1}?$ Certainly, one canonical embedding in the case of $n=1$ is the line at infinity in $\mathbb RP^2.$

Comment: Do you know the CW structure of $\mathbb{R}P^n$?

Comment: Yes, it consists of n+1 cells of dimensions from 0 to n (one of each dimension). Does this mean that my set is contractible, so the homology group is 0?

Comment: Yes @Steppewolf Btw, where did you get this question from?

Comment: Thanks! I found it on some problem set online while I was doing problems for practice.